# How do I publish a signed zipaligned Cordova app to the Google play store?

Tags: cordova, google-play

I build for release with Cordova v11
Then I sign it.
Then I upload it to the play store.
I receive a message

```
You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned. You will need to run a zip align tool on your APK and upload it again.
```

So then I used zipalign with

```
zipalign" -f -v 4 app-release.apk aligned.apk
```

When I upload that file the play store tells me

```
You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR (Jar signer CERT.DSA): JAR signature META-INF/CERT.SF indicates the APK is signed using APK Signature Scheme v2 but no such signature was found. Signature stripped?
```

If I then sign the zip aligned file and attempt to upload, the play store will tell me the file is not aligned again.

Comment: You should consider publishing as bundle instead

Comment: Thanks, I have started trying that, and I get Task :app:signReleaseBundle FAILED

Might have to open an new question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, "cordova build --release" command makes .aab, not apk. This happened after cordova 10.0.
The .aab file is placed under project\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\bundle\release.
Before,it was under ..outputs\apk\release (before cordova update).

Handling .aab is same as .apk(jarsigner and zipalign), then drag it on the playstore.

I hope this information help you.

Comment: Thanks, but I am running version 11 and --release builds an apk for me.

Comment: If you specify platform options with packageType as apk, it will still output apk.